# Turn off additional response headers from v1/eval API in MarkLogic

Tags: curl, marklogic

In MarkLlogic, when invoking the `v1/eval` endpoint, the response is peppered with "extra headers" that are not suppressed by using the `--silent` flag.

Example:
`curl --silent -u user:pass --digest -X POST --data xquery@test.xqy http://localhost:8000/v1/eval`

Where *test.xqy* contains

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

Results in something like:

```
--e17f2058da4654f7
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Primitive: integer

1
--e17f2058da4654f7
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Primitive: integer

2
--e17f2058da4654f7
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Primitive: integer

3
--e17f2058da4654f7--
```

The desired result is:

```
1
2
3
```

This is quite an effort to parse and clean up, especially in a shell script.

Is there any way to clean up the response by passing additional options to either curl or to the `v1/eval` endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited after further discussion]

*MarkLogic:*

The eval endpoint only returns multipart/mixed.  Give it a *sequence* of N and you get N boundaries.  There is no way to change this behavior for the endpoint in question. Alternative would be to create your own REST extension or a main module and use v1/invoke

*cURL:*

A data transport tool that  -by design - does not know or care about the details the content of the data transferred. It has no idea of what a multi-part message is.

So, between the two tools, there is no actual solution on it's own. Full solution would be to change one or the other or add a parsing solution for the results of the cURL command.

---

*Multi-part message quickly explained:*

There is a header of *Content-Type* that has the value of "miltipart/mixed;" followed by a boundary.

*Example:*

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--e17f2058da4654f7
```

Then after that, it follows the rules as a normal http header (header ends with newline):

- Each part starts with the boundary (which appears to always start with `--` even it not noted in the boundary as noted in the header
- Then normal header lines (like Content-Type of the part)
- Then a blank line at the end of the header.
- For convenience, there is a trailing boundary and newline which makes parsing easier.

---

You could then parse the header, find the boundary and then use standard tools. Suggestions for *nix for you to pipe the cURL results to:

- Milti-line `SED` command : eat up the text of every boundary up to and including the newline
- `AWK` script where you swich state (if start or in content, then enter boundary : state= header, if in header and enter newline, : state=content
- or Python, PERL, PHP, etc etc.

We can also leverage one part of HTTP and cURL to make it a little more simple.  You could also set the Accept-Header for the content type and define the boundary yourself. Making it predictable makes less coding:

HTTP REQUEST:

`Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=llama`

RESPONSE Header: (We can ignore since we have a predictable boundary)

`Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=llama`

Content:

```
--llama
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Primitive: integer

1
--llama
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Primitive: integer

2
--llama
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Primitive: integer

3
--llama
```

Then using a technique as above makes parsing trivial

Comment: This is probably the best available solution but I would like to be able to remove the boundary and run the query in the same way using query console and v1/eval.

Comment: You cannot remove the boundary from the server side.  A boundary is just part of a multipart message..   That endpoint is set like that because it aligns with the response from the XDBC protocol.   In addition, cURL is all about data exchange - not content parsing. For that, pass it to a tool(read: favorite glue/scripting language) who can parse the response. In query console, you have a sequence. That is not the same as a serialized (text) list, so it is never really the "same".

Comment: Of course, nothing stops you from creating your own ML REST extension to do what you need. Or perhaps a module and use V1/invoke   - then you can make the tool you need for the task that you want to accomplish